# ,Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "core_erp"

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, enterprise-library

Am trying to connect to a db (actually am put on an already built project :) ) . The code was connecting ok but after a windows issue and restroring, the following error shows up each time a DB connection is attempted.

`Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "core_erp"` ..

have installed mysql .net connector but the error still shows up.

As said that the project is already built but when the code was ported to this computer, the issue started to show up (reason to tell this is that the issue is not in the code rather possibly on the configurations)

any help appreciated.

USING MYSQL, ENT.LIBRARY , WCF, ASP.Net MVC-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue solved by installing the newer MYSQL .net connector (6.8.3).

hope this helps someone else :)