# How to use microsoft enterprise library in asp.net c# application for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, enterprise-library

I am use Database MySQL in ASP.NET c# application.When I use simple Steps for connect the MySQL database and create ADO.NET connections working fine. But I want to use Microsoft Enterprise Library for my application.I added Reference given below

1. Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
2. Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
3. Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.S
4. MySql.Data
5. MySql.Web

Below is my web.comfig code

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
      invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="db1"></dataConfiguration>
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="constr" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=db1;user id=test;persistsecurityinfo=True;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient;"/>
</connectionStrings>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

and when I use in code by below code

```
if (_connectionMode == DatabaseConnectionMode.UseConnectionStringName)
{
   _Database = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create(_dbConnectionString) as Database;
}
```

here throw the below error

> The requested database db1does not have a valid ADO.NET provider name set in the connection string.

Give me proper solution with reason why this happening.

Comment: This solution with "_Database = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create(_dbConnectionString) as Database;" is work for me

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string name needs to match the default database:

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="db1"></dataConfiguration>
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="db1" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=db1;user id=test;persistsecurityinfo=True;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Your solution I applied. And also add "EntLibContrib.Data.MySql" dll for MySQL. Now **"Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "** error arise.

Comment: What connector version you using (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438041/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-database-key-co) and see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030436/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-database-key